# Printing the incoming token in the antlr3 grammar?

Tags: antlr3

I am using antlr3. I have my parser and lexer files.I want to print the incoming token(As given by user input) in the parser file.I have tried input.LT(1).

It prints the input token(given by user) nicely. But then for future analysis I can't use this lookahead token. So is there any other commands or instruction that can print the incoming tokens?

(For example if my input is 1+2+; my token for '+' is 'PLUS', then I must print '+' not 'PLUS').

Comment: Please read this and adapt your question to make it possible that someone can help you. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual text of the token ("+"), use `token.getText()`.

To get the text representing the token name ("PLUS"), you'll have to ask the parser: `<YourParserClass>.tokenNames[token.getType()]`.

Comment: How can i get the previous and next tokens in grammar?

Comment: Where "in grammar"? Do you mean `input.LT(-1)`?

Comment: Yeah.It works.But then as I already said I cant use this lookahead token LT.Is there any replacement for this? (Like token.getText())

Comment: No, the tokens don't know by default about the other tokens. You'd either have to store the token stream and access the tokens through it, or make a custom `org.antlr.runtime.TokenSource` that would create tokens aware of their siblings (I once made tokens that hold pointers to the previous and next token through this).